# How to find the URL of a OSB proxy service which do not have wsdl associated

Tags: proxy, servicebus, osb

I have a proxy service which accepts text as request and gives text as response. I have a routed node which invokes another business service. I have to make this way because I need to add soap headers to the input before i invoke the business service. Now everything is working fine and i am able to launch test console of the proxy and get it tested. But I am not able to find the direct url to access the proxy service to share it to the customer.

My  proxy uri is for eg, /testWS/TestProxy and if i try to give http://:/testWS/TestProxy?wsdl it returns 404 error. I understand this is because there is no wsdl associated to this proxy. But how will i get this working atleast in soap ui?

Regards
Murali

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into `/sbonsole/`
2. Navigate `to Project Explorer` and find the proxy
3. Go to `Configuration Details` tab (the default tab)
4. the `Endpoint URI` field has the path details.
5. (If you weren't sure, the hostname and port are found in `/console/` -> `environment` -> `servers` - there are Listen Port fields etc)

As far as SoapUI goes, you can either treat the service as a REST service, or you can create the project without a WSDL and add stuff manually (for instance, there's a `HTTP Test Request` test step that you can use instead of a SOAP test request)

Comment: Thanks a lot Trent. It worked :) one last question - my proxy returns a string in JSON format. But when i test it from SOAP UI, the json tab shows "Not JSON content" message in the response window. Is it expected?

Comment: You probably have to set the content type correctly. This guy has a good step-by step guide for you to follow: 

http://genericparallel.com/2014/06/osb-and-json-proxies/

Answer (score 0):

To receive the response in JSON format, you must set the **Accept** header as **application/json**